# Inherit xml serialization attribute in descendant c# classes

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following base class:

```
[XmlRoot("CruiseLineRequest", IsNullable = false)]
public class CruiseLineRequestMessage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MessageHeader")]
    public MessageHeaderType MessageHeader { get; set; }
}
```

and as you can see I want to call the node **CruiseLineRequest**. I now have a descendant:

```
public class DisplayBookingRequestMessage : CruiseLineRequestMessage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayBookingRequest")]
    public DisplayBookingRequestType DisplayBookingRequestType { get; set; }
}
```

but when I serialize that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DisplayBookingRequestMessage>
  <MessageHeader SegmentId="MSGHDR">
  </MessageHeader>
  <DisplayBookingRequest SegmentId="BKDSP1" />
</DisplayBookingRequestMessage>
```

and the node is called **DisplayBookingRequestMessage**. To fix this means I have to add the same declaration as the base in my descendant:

```
[XmlRoot("CruiseLineRequest", IsNullable = false)]
public class DisplayBookingRequestMessage : CruiseLineRequestMessage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayBookingRequest")]
    public DisplayBookingRequestType DisplayBookingRequestType { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid having to add

```
[XmlRoot("CruiseLineRequest", IsNullable = false)]
```

to all my descendants?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to inform the serializer about the derived class by using the [XmlInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) attribute on the base class like:

```
[XmlRoot("CruiseLineRequest", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DisplayBookingRequestMessage))]    
public class CruiseLineRequestMessage
{
    ...
}
```

AND, then create the serializer to be of *base class* type:

```
XmlSerializer ser3 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CruiseLineRequestMessage));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however as I have a number of descendants I would prefer to use the descendant when performing the serialization in terms of keeping type safety. So while this is a solution I am hoping for something more elegant.